# JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Entity Framework object)

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, .net-3.5, jsonserializer

May be, it is not so problematic for you. but i'm trying first time with json serialization. and also read other articles in stackowerflow.

I have created Entity Framework data model.
then by method get all data from object:

```
private uqsEntities _db = new uqsEntities();
//get all data from table sysMainTableColumns where tableName=paramtableName
public List<sysMainTableColumns> getDataAboutMainTable(string tableName)
{
     return (from column in _db.sysMainTableColumns
                    where column.TableName==tableName
                    select column).ToList();

}
```

my webservice:

```
public string getDataAboutMainTable()
{
    penta.DAC.Tables dictTable = new penta.DAC.Tables();
    var result = dictTable.getDataAboutMainTable("1");
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
}
```

and jQuery ajax method

```
$('#loadData').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WS/ConstructorWS.asmx/getDataAboutMainTable",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#jsonResponse").html(msg);

                    var data = eval("(" + msg + ")");
                    //do something with data
                },
                error: function(msg) {

                }
            });
        });
```

Fails (from fairbug):

```
missing ] after element list [Break on this error] var data = eval("(" + msg + ")");
```

**ajax Response (by Firebug if I remove `var data = eval("(" + msg + ")")`):**

```
{"d":"[{\"ID\":1,\"TableName\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"d\",\"FullName\":\"f\",\"Type\":\"nvarchar(50)\",\"MeasurementUnit\":\"t         \",\"EntityState\":2,\"EntityKey\":{\"EntitySetName\":\"sysMainTableColumns\",\"EntityContainerName\":\"uqsEntities\",\"EntityKeyValues\":[{\"Key\":\"ID\",\"Value\":1}],\"IsTemporary\":false}},{\"ID\":2,\"TableName\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"e\",\"FullName\":\"e\",\"Type\":\"int\",\"MeasurementUnit\":\"r         \",\"EntityState\":2,\"EntityKey\":{\"EntitySetName\":\"sysMainTableColumns\",\"EntityContainerName\":\"uqsEntities\",\"EntityKeyValues\":[{\"Key\":\"ID\",\"Value\":2}],\"IsTemporary\":false}}]"}
```

problem with **data**, code fails there. and i think i'm not use **JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize()** method very well.

Please, tell me, what a big mistake I made in C# code?

Comment: Fails? Fails how? The `eval` is unnecessary, by the way.

Comment: @Craig-Stuntz: I think, now my question now is well formed. may be eval not unnecessary. but why ajax Responce is include tags like ":\"?

Comment: Looks to me like escaping the quote marks. BTW, it's a bad idea to serialize entities directly as `JavaScriptSerializer` will die if one happens to contain a circular reference.

Comment: @Craig-Stuntz: ok. Please, advice me, how to getdata from sysMainTableColumns table by Entity Framework, and use it with jquery? may be some tutorials, it is just test application. I can change everything. i just want to learn to do this.

Comment: I project onto an anonymous type. Change `select column` to `select new { Id = column.Id, // etc.`

Comment: @Craig-Stuntz: i changed it to an anonymous type.    select new { tableName = column.TableName, columnname = column.Name"
now ajaxResponce return 
    {"d":"[{\"tableName\":\"1\",\"columnname\":\"d\"},{\"tableName\":\"1\",\"columnname\":\"e\"}]"}

    jQuery.each(msg, function(rec) {
    alert(this.tableName);
}); 

and alerting "undefined"

Comment: `$.each(msg.d, function ...)` That ".d" is important!

Comment: thanks, you answered to all my question. and i found it difficult to check true answer :) how can i do this?

Comment: Now that I know what the problem is, I'll put it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need `eval`. jQuery does that for you when you specify `dataType: "json"`
2. It's a bad idea to serialize entities directly as `JavaScriptSerializer` will die if one happens to contain a circular reference.
3. Don't forget the `d`! That's inserted by WCF services to work around a security hole in some browsers when the root object is an array.

Comment: Been wondering about that 'd'. Do know where I can find some more information about that?

Comment: It's a security feature since top-level arrays can be attacked in JavaScript when fetched with a `GET`. Same reason that `return Json` doesn't work in MVC 2 with a GET request unless you explicitly turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging with Firebug or Fiddler to see what the JSON content looks like?

Comment: yes, sorry, i forget to publicate. please, whatch in question content