# When deserializing JSON from within a C# program, should I ever need to use anything other than JavaScriptSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

.NET provides the JavaScriptSerializer class in  the
System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace. (provided in System.Web.Extensions.dll)

It was originally intended to support AJAX web server apps, but the class can be used by any application (client, server, hybrid, anything) that serializes and deserializes .NET classes to JSON. I have a desktop app that captures screenshots and uploads to Facebook, and uses this class to deserialize the response.

would I ever want to look elsewhere for JSON deserialization from within .NET?

If so, why?  and where would I Look?

---

If not, then why does JSON.Net exist?  Is it strictly for historical purposes? (ie, because it was created by the community before the JavaScriptSerializer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case there are various reasons that prevent me to use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). Here are some of them.

**1) Ugly deserialization when dealing with anonymous types**

<strike>While the usage is fairly straight forward for serialization:</strike>

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
String json = serializer.Serialize(data);
```

For deserialization however, there is a minor annoyance in that the deserializer accepts a generic type along with the content:

```
serializer.Deserialize<T>(String s)
```

this can be a problem if the type T is not known at compile time and needs to be dynamic. The work around is a bit ugly as I learnt because it uses reflection to create a generic method (but it works)

```
var result = typeof(JavaScriptSerializer).GetMethod("Deserialize") 
             .MakeGenericMethod(JsonDataType) 
             .Invoke(serializer, new object[] { inputContent });
```

**Please note**: according to Dave Ward comment on this answer there's a `DeserializeObject()` that can be used to prevent this.

**2) Cannot handle circular references**

I have seen this using [Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449980/javascriptserializer-serializeentity-framework-object), Linq to SQL, NHibernate, NetTiers and even when using [Castle's proxy](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/8610457a63ca8ef9).

According to [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/354859/entity-framework-entitycollection-and-datacontractjsonserializer) the circular reference exception will be raised when a navigable relation is double-sided (can access both sides of the relation), so the first thing to do is disable one side of the relation. The exception will also be thrown when you use 1:1 relations (or 1:0..1 or any relation causing the creation of an EntityReference type property), in this case the exception will be of type `System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssociationType`.

The solution to this is to make the serializer ignore the properties of type EntityReference, using an empty implementation of a class deriving from JavaScriptConverter and registering it using the RegisterConverters method of the JavaScriptSerializer object.

**3) Useful features that leads to less testable code**

A useful feature of the JavaScriptSerializer is that you can also implement a custom JavaScriptConverter and pass that in to JavaScriptSerializer for fine-grained control over the serialization/deserialization. However, for it to be really useful you need to know the types at compile time and have references to those types. This really limits the usefulness of this feature because by referencing those classes your code becomes tightly coupled so you cannot easily use it in something like an MVC filter.

For these reasons I have often ended up using Json.NET.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Re #1, you're looking for JavaScriptSerializer's DeserializeObject() method instead of Deserialize().  It's nice and easy/flexible.

Comment: @Dave Ward: Good catch! I have edited the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

I use the JavaScriptSerializer on a wide variety of scenarios, it never let me down, and never needed to look elsewhere for other solutions... :)

...but i do know that JSON.net has some added values like LINQ to JSON, which i never needed, and nice JSON formatting but as Serializing goes JavaScriptSerializer does the work fine.

Comment: hmmm, what does "LINQ to JSON" give me if I already have LINQ to Objects?  Does it de-serialize only the fields I select?

Comment: He's talking about the API LINQ to Json http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/02/11/linq-to-json-beta.aspx