# Parse JSON results - C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

I'm trying to parse a Json result from an API and the returned result of the data seems a bit difficult for me to grasp.

- It appears to return a 'header' and then the items (...see raw result example).
- I tried to parse this using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)

I am not familiar with Json.NET nor with Json for that matter.

- How do i parse the results and map it to a class?
- Either using JSON.Net or another tool.

Thanks

### Raw Returned Result (Json)

```
{
"code": 0,
"message": "Successful",
"partials": {
    "_key": "partial",
    "0": {
        "datetime": "2011-03-08 16:22:51",
        "customer_id": "373263",
        "domain": "xyz.com ** deleted 2011-04-08 18:26:55 UTC**",
        "name": "Joe Customer",
        "phone": "1234567894",
        "email": "joecustomer@test.com",
        "offer": "",
        "pub_id": "",
        "sub_id": "",
        "data1": "", ... , "data3": "",
        "custom1": "", ..., "custom8": "" 
    },
    "1": {
        "datetime": "2011-03-08 16:43:11",
        "customer_id": "373296",
        "domain": "abc.com ** deleted 2011-04-08 18:26:55 UTC**",
        "name": "Jane Customer",
        "phone": "1234567891",
        "email": "janecustomer@test.com",
        "offer": "",
        "pub_id": "",
        "sub_id": "",
        "data1": "", ... , "data3": "",
        "custom1": "", ..., "custom8": "" 
    }
}
```

}

### My Attempt

```
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (request.HaveResponse == true)
        {
            Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

            JObject o = JObject.Parse(responseString);

            IList<JToken> results = o["partials"].Children().ToList();

            IList<bbParial> oResults = new List<bbPartial>();

            foreach (JToken t in results)
            {
                if (t.ToString().Contains("partial"))
                {
                    // Do nothing this is the header
                }
                else
                {
                    bbPartial bbp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bbPartial>(t.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

### Sample Class

```
public class bbpartial
{
    public string _key;
    public string datetime;
    public string customer_id;
    public string domain;
    public string name;
    public string phone;
    public string email;
    public string offer;
    public string pub_id;
    public string sub_id;
    public string data1;
    public string data2;
    public string data3;
    public string custom1;
    public string custom2;
    public string custom3;
    public string custom4;
    public string custom5;
    public string custom6;
    public string custom7;
    public string custom8;
}
```

Comment: Could you post some of the code you've tried already?

Comment: Could you post an example of the class you want to populate also.

Comment: Have you tried the JavaScriptSerializer in the .NET framework? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx

Comment: see also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523410 - *Why would I ever use anything other than JavaScriptSerializer?*

Comment: Thanks goalie, this is actually a winforms application...sorry, should have mentioned that up front.

Comment: It should still work, I guess you'd just have a bunch of ugly references though.

Answer (score 2):

```
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jasonExample);

Customer customerOne = new Customer()
 {
   Name =(string)jsonObj.selectToken("partials[0].name")
 }
```

Does that work?  Is it helpful?